# Paypal Recurring Payment API CALL when taking money

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring, trial

I am writing a subscription where I need to provide users a month trial and charge $5.00 after trial is finished. I just found an amazing code to do that for me.

I also have setup paypalpro plus recurring payments

This is the link

https://github.com/krio/paypal-recurring-subscriptions

Questions:

1- How to make first month Free Trial? 
2- I need to update users billing and update their payment in my database so it can calculate their subscription, how would i get to call from paypal to my files to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using subscriptions and you are wanting to make the first month a free trial, you would need to pass over the following variables and values.

```
a1=0  
p1=1  
t1=M
```

You can find a description of all of the variables for subscriptions [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU).

If you are wanting to get updates back to your system/database to update your profiles and etc, you can use IPN to do this.  [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) ([IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.